# C# sending emails using domain SMPT or Sendgrid?

Tags: c#, azure, email, sendgrid

I got a api that generate a number and sends it the client email account for verification.

Till now i have been using the free version of Send grid, but recently noticed that some off the emails are being blocked, or black listed.

This is the error i was getting.
: "522 email sent from 149.72.39.137 found on industry IP blacklists (Spamhaus/Invaluement/ReturnPath) on 2020/09/13 20:32:34 BST. To protect our customers, we use leading industry providers of blacklists to ensure only good senders can send email to us. If believe this is a mistake, please contact them directly as there is nothing our Postmaster will be able to do."

The support team at Send Grid have managed to get my account working again.

But as i am on shared server plan(Free account), there is still a possibility this could arise due to various reasons such as other users.

To avoid this i did some research and found that using my own domain, i could create a email account and using c# and the smpt server details send email directly .

Would there be any disadvantage of doing it this that way?

Answer (score 0):

Only having a domain doesn't replace SendGrid. SendGrid is providing you with SMTP servers for sending and delivering huge amounts of emails reliably. You could get an SMTP server somewhere and use it to send out the emails using C#. However, configuring your own SMTP server requires good knowledge of the underlying technologies and it is a lot of work. In case you don't want to do that, you could get a cheap hosting plan from some provider, but keep in mind that you are then also sharing your SMTP server with other people. So in the end this is no different than having a shared SendGrid account.

Best bet for you is to pay the $80 bucks and get a dedicated IP plan from SendGrid together with a domain so you can properly setup SPF and DKIM. Cheaping out on your email infrastructure will result in issues later on.

For developing and testing, another option would be to get a cheap paid email plan from a popular provider and try to use it's SMTP server to send out emails. E.g. Outlook.

Comment: Thanks

I have domain called e.g. www.abc.com. I have a yearly hosting package . I can create unlimited email accounts.

I am thinking about creating an email e.g. app@abc.com, and using the steps i would take to set it up using outlook, i am thinking i could so the same in theory using c#. So when someone gets an email from me it will be app@abc.com

My email qty at the moment is very low, maybe 10-20 a month.

Comment: If you want to go that way, it should be easily possible with c#. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1